# Mulesoft MEL Expression Get String Value Of Payload Data Type

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio, munit

I want to extract my payload's class name in a MUnit assert so I can verify the payload is always of the correct type. I've tried 2 MEL expressions, but both return null in the MEL expression evaluator. The funny thing is that if I remove the .name part of the expression then I see a key called "name" with the value that I need. Any ideas?

```
payload.class.name
message.dataType.type.name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is:  #[payload.getClass().getSimpleName()]

Comment: Works great, thanks! Won't give the full class name for the record but good enough for my purposes. I'm sure there's an equivalent method for the full class name.

Comment: You can use getCanonicalName() for full class name.  getSimpleName() will for instance give you "String" while CanonicalName will give "java.lang.String".  There are other options as well, but for most cases that should cover you.